# Weird behavior of MSI installation

Tags: windows, windows-installer

I have created an MSI installer using Wise Installation Express 7.0

Recently one client has reported and issue after our new update on Win 7 32 bit:

He launch our update msi, which in turn ask him to remove the previous installation and it removes successfully. This should not happen as I have changed the product code of MSI and its a new product and it should install parallel to the old product.

Now, again when he launch the msi to install the latest build it show welcome dialog and but on  clicking on next everything disappears. msiexec.exe also quits from the processes.

When he tries to replicate the same on Win Xp(32 and 64), Win Vista (32 and 64) and win 7 64 bit machine it does not replicate.

I have used
Windows Clean Up utilities
CCleaner
Total Uninstall
but everything fails.

Can anyone suggest what is the problem?

As it runs fine on all other system. I have even created a Windows 7 32-bit virtual machine and it installs parallel to the old product on that machine too

Comment: Is he running on an encrypted drive? MSI installers don't work if encyrpted.

Comment: No, even comression is turned off

Comment: Are there entries in the upgrade table of your MSI? If so, what are they?

Answer (score 0):

Generate an installation log file.
Check Windows event log.